# How to view dropdown menu (data validation) with Google Sheets on my website

Tags: google-sheets, embed

I know how to embed a Google Sheet onto a website. My issue is that my sheet has a dropdown menu (created with data validation "List from a range") does not appear when the sheet is viewed as a website. I would like the dropdown menu to appear when embedded on a website. Is there a way to do this?

I expect to see the full list of countries when I click the dropdown button
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW9hm.png)

But when I view the Google Sheets webpage I cannot change the country.

Here is a link to the Google Sheet (web version):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTRghDGSNADQc2njXvT6qOfFvGv0DWW6vdXRylCE8s987PpN4skigV3cGcZFmJFJghgasyuEOjmNn1m/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit operations are not supported

I'm afraid this is not possible since using a dropdown menu is considered an edit operation. Edit operations are not allowed on Web published versions of the Google Spreadsheets.

A workaround here would be sharing your Spreadsheet with a link and edit permissions to anyone. `Share> Get Link> Anyone with the link> Select Editor in the permissions dropdown`

If this a really important feature for you, submit this as a Feedback from the Spreadsheet page: `Help> Report a problem> Send Feedback`.